# Como eu crio um loop que permita cancelar a ordem anterior quando passar de um certo valor?

Tags: c, c++, mql4

Boa noite. A seguinte linguagem é MQL5. Estou a criar um robô para o MetaTrader 5. Eu criei depois de muitas horas o código que aparecer a seguir. Eu na altura fiz os comentários em inglês tal e qual como no tutorial pois o vídeo estava em inglês. O meu objetivo é fazer com que uma ordem BUY seja criada sempre que o valor de RSI(Relative Strenght Index) passe a ser maior que 70, e mal passe a ser menor que 70, que crie uma ordem SELL, deletando a ordem anterior. Como a estratégia vai sempre responder aos valores de RSI, ela não precisa de Stop Loss ou Take Profit. Tem algumas coisas que não sei o que fazem ou se realmente são necessárias. Eu gostava de saber o que fiz errado.
Obrigado a quem poder ajudar.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                     RSIrobot.mq5 |
//|                        Copyright 2021, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2021, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Include                                                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#include <Expert\Expert.mqh>
//--- available signals
#include <Expert\Signal\SignalRSI.mqh>
//--- available trailing
#include <Expert\Trailing\TrailingNone.mqh>
//--- available money management
#include <Expert\Money\MoneyFixedLot.mqh>
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Inputs                                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//--- inputs for expert
input string             Expert_Title         ="RSIrobot";  // Document name
ulong                    Expert_MagicNumber   =18801;       //
bool                     Expert_EveryTick     =false;       //
//--- inputs for main signal
input int                Signal_ThresholdOpen =10;          // Signal threshold value to open    [0...100]
input int                Signal_ThresholdClose=10;          // Signal threshold value to close [0...100]
input double             Signal_PriceLevel    =0.0;         // Price level to execute a deal
input double             Signal_StopLevel     =50.0;        // Stop Loss level (in points)
input double             Signal_TakeLevel     =50.0;        // Take Profit level (in points)
input int                Signal_Expiration    =4;           // Expiration of pending orders (in bars)
input int                Signal_RSI_PeriodRSI =14;          // Relative Strength Index(14,...) M1     Period of calculation
input ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE Signal_RSI_Applied   =PRICE_CLOSE; // Relative Strength Index(14,...) M1 Prices series
input double             Signal_RSI_Weight    =1.0;         // Relative Strength Index(14,...) M1   Weight [0...1.0]
//--- inputs for money
input double             Money_FixLot_Percent =100.0;       // Percent
input double             Money_FixLot_Lots    =0.05;        // Fixed volume
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global expert object                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CExpert ExtExpert;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//--- Initializing expert
if(!ExtExpert.Init(Symbol(),PERIOD_M1,Expert_EveryTick,Expert_MagicNumber))
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing expert");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- Creating signal
CExpertSignal *signal=new CExpertSignal;
if(signal==NULL)
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating signal");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//---
ExtExpert.InitSignal(signal);
signal.ThresholdOpen(Signal_ThresholdOpen);
signal.ThresholdClose(Signal_ThresholdClose);
signal.PriceLevel(Signal_PriceLevel);
signal.StopLevel(Signal_StopLevel);
signal.TakeLevel(Signal_TakeLevel);
signal.Expiration(Signal_Expiration);
//--- Creating filter CSignalRSI
CSignalRSI *filter0=new CSignalRSI;
if(filter0==NULL)
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating filter0");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
signal.AddFilter(filter0);
//--- Set filter parameters
filter0.Period(PERIOD_M1);
filter0.PeriodRSI(Signal_RSI_PeriodRSI);
filter0.Applied(Signal_RSI_Applied);
filter0.Weight(Signal_RSI_Weight);
//--- Creation of trailing object
CTrailingNone *trailing=new CTrailingNone;
if(trailing==NULL)
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating trailing");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- Add trailing to expert (will be deleted automatically))
if(!ExtExpert.InitTrailing(trailing))
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing trailing");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
 //--- Set trailing parameters
 //--- Creation of money object
CMoneyFixedLot *money=new CMoneyFixedLot;
if(money==NULL)
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error creating money");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- Add money to expert (will be deleted automatically))
if(!ExtExpert.InitMoney(money))
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing money");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- Set money parameters
money.Percent(Money_FixLot_Percent);
money.Lots(Money_FixLot_Lots);
//--- Check all trading objects parameters
if(!ExtExpert.ValidationSettings())
  {
   //--- failed
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- Tuning of all necessary indicators
if(!ExtExpert.InitIndicators())
  {
   //--- failed
   printf(__FUNCTION__+": error initializing indicators");
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
   return(INIT_FAILED);
  }
//--- ok
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Deinitialization function of the expert                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
   ExtExpert.Deinit();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Tick" event handler function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
   ExtExpert.OnTick();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Trade" event handler function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTrade()
 {
  ExtExpert.OnTrade();
 }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Timer" event handler function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
  {
  ExtExpert.OnTimer();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma de eventos utilizada no codigo nao permite o comportamento desejado. O sinalidor do RSI vai indicar compra quando esta abaixo de, digamos de 30, com peso 10. Quando volta para cima de 30 pode estar indicando ainda compra com peso 2. Isso quer dizer que pra voce fazer o comportamento que deseja precisara alterar o codigo do gerador de evento e suas pontuacoes. Veja o codigo na area de include que fala sobre o gerador de eventos do RSI para tambem saber o que desligar da execucao padrao via chamada a funcao Pattern ou Weigth (uma analise do padrao pode ficar sempre ligada, mas nao ter contribuicao pro peso).

Outra coisa eh que uma ordem de compra pode ser aberta e fechada e nao ter a necessidade de se gerar uma ordem de venda. A geracao de uma posicao oposta para encerrar uma posicao aberta pode ser problematica se estiver trabalhando com um tipo de conta chamado hedge.